# A balloon popped in a room

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, gas

This question is Question 23 from CAP exam 2017.

An inflated balloon, filled with a gas of temperature T, is held in a room with the same temperature.  If we make a small hole on the side of the balloon and let the gas escape, which statement is true about the temperature T’ of the gas right after leaving the balloon?

The correct answer according to the solutions is "T′> T". However, I cannot imagine why this would be the case.

By all reasoning, this is an adiabatic expansion. That means $PV^\gamma$ is conserved. Since $\gamma$ is bigger than $1$, this means that $PV$ should decrease when $P$ decreases, and thus temperature should decrease.

As another reasoning, the gas inside is doing work by expanding outwards, and thus the energy would decrease.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in saying that the gas remaining at any time within the balloon has experienced an adiabatic reversible expansion, so its temperature is cooler than initially.  But, the problem does not appear to be asking you to compare the temperature of the gas exiting the hole at any time with the temperature at time zero.  It seems to be asking you to compare the temperature of the gas exiting the hole at time t with the temperature of the gas remaining within the balloon at time t.

The gas passing through the hole at time t is experiencing a change in pressure at constant enthalpy per unit mass.  This is the so-called Joule Thomson effect, and the change in the gas temperature is determined by the Joule-Thomson coefficient:  the partial derivative of temperature with respect to pressure at constant enthalpy.  For an ideal gas, this is zero, but, for most real gases at room temperature and approximately atmospheric pressure, the Joule-Thomson coefficient is positive.  In my judgment, this is what the problem statement was driving at.  In any event, it was a pretty ambiguous (crappy) statement, since, for a handful of gases under these conditions (e.g., He and H2), the JT coefficient is negative.

Comment: I don't quite understand the distinction in your first paragraph. I'd have thought the temperature at time zero (*T*) should be equal to the temperature of the gas remaining in the balloon at any time *t*. If we have an arbitrarily large balloon, wouldn't a small amount of gas escaping have an arbitrarily small effect on the temperature of the gas remaining inside the balloon?

Comment: It depends on if the gas within the balloon has time to equilibrate thermally with the gas outside the balloon.  If the gas escapes slowly enough, then, yes, but, if not (and the rubber provides some mild insulation), then no.  So this is a judgment call (that can be quantified if we know the escape rate and the thermal conductivity of the rubber).  And, of course, at very short times, the pressure of the gas remaining within the balloon hasn't changed much, so, either way, neither has its temperature.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I need further help, however. The first issue is that the temperature T, by the construction of the question, is the temperature of the gas/room at before the hole is poked.

The second, and more pressing issue, is that a look at wikipedia gave that the temperature would decrease with a positive coefficient. And indeed, most gas have positive coefficients at Standard Temp and Pressure.

How do we deal with this?

Comment: I don't understand your first question, but, as you point out in your second question, a positive JT coefficient would mean that the gas experiencing a pressure drop through a porous plug, valve, or hole would cool a little, rather than heat.

Comment: So we agree that the gas should cool down then?

Comment: Yes, unless its a Helium balloon, in which case its temperature will rise (a little).